# Get all child views inside LinearLayout at once

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout`, which contains several child `TextViews`. How can I get child views of that LinerLayout using a loop?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

Use `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt(int index)`.

**Example:**

```
LinearLayout ll = …
final int childCount = ll.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      View v = ll.getChildAt(i);
      // Do something with v.
      // …
}
```

Comment: Hi Yashwanth Kumar, can i get all TextViews in that Linearlayout?

Comment: @hai-nguyen: You can use if (v instanceof TextView) {...} for that.

Comment: what if one of the child is a ViewGroup and we want to get all those childs as well?

Comment: How can i get total no of `buttons` added in linear layout and devide it by *2* ? My purpose is to show 2 rows of buttons using *linear layout*.

Answer (score 49):

```
((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content));// you can use this in an Activity to get your layout root view, then pass it to findAllEdittexts() method below.
```

**Here I am iterating only EdiTexts, if you want all Views you can replace EditText with View.**

```
SparseArray<EditText> array = new SparseArray<EditText>();

private void findAllEdittexts(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
            findAllEdittexts((ViewGroup) view);
        else if (view instanceof EditText) {
            EditText edittext = (EditText) view;
            array.put(editText.getId(), editText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, doing it recursively is because `getChildAt` returns only direct children

Comment: Wouldn't it cause a stackoverflow error if we call "too" recursively?

Answer (score 10):

It is easier with Kotlin using for-in loop:

```
for (childView in ll.children) {
     //childView is a child of ll         
}
```

Here `ll` is `id` of `LinearLayout` defined in layout XML.

Answer (score 8):

use this

```
    final int childCount = mainL.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
          View element = mainL.getChildAt(i);

        // EditText
        if (element instanceof EditText) {
            EditText editText = (EditText)element;
            System.out.println("ELEMENTS EditText getId=>"+editText.getId()+ " getTag=>"+element.getTag()+
            " getText=>"+editText.getText());
        }

        // CheckBox
        if (element instanceof CheckBox) {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)element;
            System.out.println("ELEMENTS CheckBox getId=>"+checkBox.getId()+ " getTag=>"+checkBox.getTag()+
            " getText=>"+checkBox.getText()+" isChecked=>"+checkBox.isChecked());
        }

        // DatePicker
        if (element instanceof DatePicker) {
            DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)element;
            System.out.println("ELEMENTS DatePicker getId=>"+datePicker.getId()+ " getTag=>"+datePicker.getTag()+
            " getDayOfMonth=>"+datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
        }

        // Spinner
        if (element instanceof Spinner) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)element;
            System.out.println("ELEMENTS Spinner getId=>"+spinner.getId()+ " getTag=>"+spinner.getTag()+
            " getSelectedItemId=>"+spinner.getSelectedItemId()+
            " getSelectedItemPosition=>"+spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()+
            " getTag(key)=>"+spinner.getTag(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get all views from any type of layout

```
public List<View> getAllViews(ViewGroup layout){
        List<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0; i< layout.getChildCount(); i++){
            views.add(layout.getChildAt(i));
        }
        return views;
}
```

Get all TextView from any type of layout

```
public List<TextView> getAllTextViews(ViewGroup layout){
        List<TextView> views = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0; i< layout.getChildCount(); i++){
            View v =layout.getChildAt(i);
            if(v instanceof TextView){
                views.add((TextView)v);
            }
        }
        return views;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get all views of a view plus its children recursively in Kotlin:

```
private fun View.getAllViews(): List<View> {
    if (this !is ViewGroup || childCount == 0) return listOf(this)

    return children
            .toList()
            .flatMap { it.getAllViews() }
            .plus(this as View)
}
```