# Multiple TextViews with one ID

Tags: java, android

How do I create multiple `TextView`s with one ID in one layout? This is my XML:

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tooltext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tooltext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tooltext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

and this my Java code

```
TextView lVl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tooltext);
lVl.setText("b a g i n n e r");
```

When I run, only one `TextView` appears. Why?

Comment: It's not really possible like that. What's the reason to not just give them different ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You can't**

IDs are layout-wide unique.

You could not name them but put in one layout.

After that circulate over them inside that layout and set the same value to all of them.  Like here: [Get all child views inside LinearLayout at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784418/get-all-child-views-inside-linearlayout-at-once)

Comment: Are you sure? Why don't you try it?

Comment: @mTak practically you can name 2 views the same in 1 layout and it would compile. But what the point of it? findViewByID return only 1 view. That would make unpredictable code, and would not help the author in any significant way.

Comment: I already mentioned it is not a good practice, it is not recommended but **it is possible**

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible like that. You can use ListView

Comment: Are you able to give sample code?

Comment: Are you sure? Why don't you try it?