# How to make all views unclickable

Tags: android

I have a `LinearLayout` which contains many Views (`Button`s and `TextView`s) and I want to make every view inside it unclickable until I process the server request. How can I do that?

Comment: You may achieve what you want by looking at [How to get all child view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784418/get-all-child-views-inside-linearlayout-at-once) and [setClickable() doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setClickable(boolean))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your LinearLayout inside a Relative, and then add another Relative above your linear, with clickable = true.

I suggest you also add a progressbar, and maybe some background opacity so the user knows its loading.
So when you are waiting for the request you set the relative that contains the progressbar visibility to visible, and when it has finished you set it back to gone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">             
         <!-Add your elements-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/semi_gray"
         android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_mid_large"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_mid_large"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try
`myView.setEnabled(false);`

or

`myView.setClickable(false); myView.setFocusable(false);`

Basically an `enabled false` doesn't respond to any response and a `clickable false` still responds when setting at runtime.